# NDK Code crashing in few HTC lollipop devices and few other devices by giving Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

Below code is used to scale the image border by dragging the edges. It works fine in Moto X, nexus 5x, few other devices and emulators. But it crashes on HTC ONE(Lollipop 5.0.2) and few other devices too. I think this is due to heavy graphics processing. Please some help me in providing the fix.

> This is the C Code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <android/bitmap.h>
//#include <asm/io.h>
#define LOG_TAG "System.out"
#define LOGD(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGI(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)

int *colorRed;
int *colorGreen;
int *colorBlue;
int *colorsP;

int *colorAlpha;
int _width,_height;
jintArray imagecolors;


static long SinXDivX_Table_8[(2<<8)+1];
double MySin(double x){
     double absx;
     absx = x;
     if(x<0) absx = -x;

     double x2 = absx*absx;
     double x3 = x2*absx;
     if(absx<1)    return (1-2*x2+x3);
     else if(absx<2) return (4-8*absx+5*x2-x3);
     else return 0;
}

int getAlpha(int i, int j) {
    return (*(colorsP+j*_width+i) >> 24)&0xFF;
}

int getRedColor(int i,int j){

    //return *(colorRed+j*_width+i);
    return (*(colorsP+j*_width+i) >> 16)&0xFF;
}

int getGreenColor(int i,int j){
    //return *(colorGreen+j*_width+i);
    return (*(colorsP+j*_width+i) >> 8)&0xFF;
}

int getBlueColor(int i,int j){
    //return *(colorBlue+j*_width+i);
    return (*(colorsP+j*_width+i))&0xFF;
}

    /**
     * �õ�x*x+y*y��ֵ
     * @param x
     * @param y
     * @return
     */
 double hypotsq(double x,double y){
        return x*x+y*y;
    }

void mapping(JNIEnv *env,jintArray image,int x,int y,double max_dist,
                       double orig_x,double orig_y,double cur_x,double cur_y){
          // if(mode == 120){
            float u = 0,v = 0;
            float fu = x,fv = y;
            double dx = x - orig_x;
            double dy = y - orig_y;
            long i,j;
            int i1,j1,_i,_j,i2,j2;
            float du;
            float dv;
            int colorpix = 0;
            int red,green,blue,alpha;
            double max_dist_sq = max_dist*max_dist;
            double mou_dx = cur_x - orig_x;
            //����-------^_^
            mou_dx = mou_dx/4;
            //--------------
            double mou_dy = cur_y - orig_y;
            //����-------^_^
            mou_dy = mou_dy/4;
            //-----------
            if(dx > -max_dist&&dx<max_dist&&dy>-max_dist&&dy<max_dist){
                double rsq = hypotsq(dx, dy);
                if(rsq < max_dist_sq){
                        //λ��
                        double msq = hypotsq(dx - mou_dx,dy - mou_dy);
                        double edge_dist = max_dist_sq - rsq;
                        double a = edge_dist/(edge_dist + msq);
                        a *=a;
                        fu -= a*mou_dx; //ӳ���ĸ�������
                        fv -= a*mou_dy; //ӳ���ĸ�������

                    u = fu;
                    v = fv;
                    {
                    u = u<(_width-1)?u:(_width-1);
                    v = v<(_height-1)?v:(_height-1);

                    u = u>0?u:0;
                    v = v>0?v:0;
                    }
    //              i = (int)u; //��ӦԴͼ��X������������
    //              j = (int)v; //��ӦԴͼ��Y������������
    //              du = u-i;//С���㲿��
    //              dv = v-j;//С���㲿��
                    long intu = (long)(u*(1 << 16)); //�Ŵ�
                    long intv = (long)(v*(1 << 16)); //�Ŵ�

                    i = intu >> 16; //Ȼ������С�õ���������
                    j = intv >> 16; //Ȼ������С�õ���������

                    long idu = (intu & 0xFFFF)>> 8;  //�õ�С������
                    long idv = (intv & 0xFFFF)>> 8;  //�õ�С������

                    long _idu = (256-idu);     //�൱��û�Ŵ�ǰ��(1-du)֮���
                    long _idv = (256-idv);

                    i1 = (i+1)<(_width-1)?(i+1):(_width-1);//Math.min(i+1, width-1);
                    j1 = (j+1)<(_height-1)?(j+1):(_height-1);//Math.min(j+1, height-1);
                    //*******************************************˫���Բ�ֵ�㷨***************************************************//
                    alpha = (_idu*_idv*getAlpha(i, j)+_idu*idv*getAlpha(i, j1)+
                             idu*_idv*getAlpha(i1, j)+idu*idv*getAlpha(i1,j1))>>16;

                    red = (_idu*_idv*getRedColor(i, j)+_idu*idv*getRedColor(i, j1)+
                            idu*_idv*getRedColor(i1, j)+idu*idv*getRedColor(i1,j1))>>16;

                    green = (_idu*_idv*getGreenColor(i, j)+_idu*idv*getGreenColor(i, j1)+
                            idu*_idv*getGreenColor(i1, j)+idu*idv*getGreenColor(i1,j1))>>16;

                    blue = (_idu*_idv*getBlueColor(i, j)+_idu*idv*getBlueColor(i, j1)+
                            idu*_idv*getBlueColor(i1, j)+idu*idv*getBlueColor(i1,j1))>>16;

                    //*******************************************���ξ����ֵ�㷨****************************************************//
                    int red3, green3, blue3, alpha3;
                    i2 = (i+2)<(_width-1)?(i+2):(_width-1);
                    j2 = (j+2)<(_height-1)?(j+2):(_height-1);
                    _i = (i-1)>0?(i-1):0;
                    _j = (j-1)>0?(j-1):0;
                    long A[4] = {SinXDivX_Table_8[(1<<8)+idu],SinXDivX_Table_8[idu+0],SinXDivX_Table_8[(1<<8)-idu],SinXDivX_Table_8[(2<<8)-idu]};
                    long C[4] = {SinXDivX_Table_8[(1<<8)+idv],
                                   SinXDivX_Table_8[idv+0],
                                   SinXDivX_Table_8[(1<<8)-idv],
                                   SinXDivX_Table_8[(2<<8)-idv]};

                    int alphaB[16] = {getAlpha(_i, _j),  getAlpha(_i,j), getAlpha(_i,j1),  getAlpha(_i,j2),
                                      getAlpha(i,_j),    getAlpha(i,j),  getAlpha(i,j1),   getAlpha(i,j2),
                                      getAlpha(i1,_j),   getAlpha(i1,j), getAlpha(i1,j1),  getAlpha(i1,j2),
                                      getAlpha(i2,_j),   getAlpha(i2,j), getAlpha(i2,j1),  getAlpha(i2,j2)};
                    double aA_B[4] = {(A[0]*alphaB[0]+A[1]*alphaB[4]+A[2]*alphaB[8]+A[3]*alphaB[12]),
                                      (A[0]*alphaB[1]+A[1]*alphaB[5]+A[2]*alphaB[9]+A[3]*alphaB[13]),
                                      (A[0]*alphaB[2]+A[1]*alphaB[6]+A[2]*alphaB[10]+A[3]*alphaB[14]),
                                      (A[0]*alphaB[3]+A[1]*alphaB[7]+A[2]*alphaB[11]+A[3]*alphaB[15])};
                    alpha3 = (int)(aA_B[0]*C[0]+aA_B[1]*C[1]+aA_B[2]*C[2]+aA_B[3]*C[3])>>16;

                    //��ɫ
                    int redB[16] = {getRedColor(_i, _j),  getRedColor(_i,j), getRedColor(_i,j1),  getRedColor(_i,j2),
                                       getRedColor(i,_j),    getRedColor(i,j),  getRedColor(i,j1),   getRedColor(i,j2),
                                       getRedColor(i1,_j),   getRedColor(i1,j), getRedColor(i1,j1),  getRedColor(i1,j2),
                                       getRedColor(i2,_j),   getRedColor(i2,j), getRedColor(i2,j1),  getRedColor(i2,j2)};

                    double A_B[4] = {(A[0]*redB[0]+A[1]*redB[4]+A[2]*redB[8]+A[3]*redB[12]),
                                      (A[0]*redB[1]+A[1]*redB[5]+A[2]*redB[9]+A[3]*redB[13]),
                                      (A[0]*redB[2]+A[1]*redB[6]+A[2]*redB[10]+A[3]*redB[14]),
                                      (A[0]*redB[3]+A[1]*redB[7]+A[2]*redB[11]+A[3]*redB[15])};
                    red3 = (int)(A_B[0]*C[0]+A_B[1]*C[1]+A_B[2]*C[2]+A_B[3]*C[3])>>16;
                    //��ɫ
                    int greenB[16] = {getGreenColor(_i, _j),  getGreenColor(_i,j), getGreenColor(_i,j1),  getGreenColor(_i,j2),
                                         getGreenColor(i,_j),    getGreenColor(i,j),  getGreenColor(i,j1),   getGreenColor(i,j2),
                                         getGreenColor(i1,_j),   getGreenColor(i1,j), getGreenColor(i1,j1),  getGreenColor(i1,j2),
                                         getGreenColor(i2,_j),   getGreenColor(i2,j), getGreenColor(i2,j1),  getGreenColor(i2,j2)};
                    double gA_B[4] = {(A[0]*greenB[0]+A[1]*greenB[4]+A[2]*greenB[8]+A[3]*greenB[12]),
                                      (A[0]*greenB[1]+A[1]*greenB[5]+A[2]*greenB[9]+A[3]*greenB[13]),
                                      (A[0]*greenB[2]+A[1]*greenB[6]+A[2]*greenB[10]+A[3]*greenB[14]),
                                      (A[0]*greenB[3]+A[1]*greenB[7]+A[2]*greenB[11]+A[3]*greenB[15])};
                    green3 = (int)(gA_B[0]*C[0]+gA_B[1]*C[1]+gA_B[2]*C[2]+gA_B[3]*C[3])>>16;
                    //��ɫ
                    int blueB[16] = {getBlueColor(_i, _j),  getBlueColor(_i,j), getBlueColor(_i,j1),  getBlueColor(_i,j2),
                                        getBlueColor(i,_j),    getBlueColor(i,j),  getBlueColor(i,j1),   getBlueColor(i,j2),
                                        getBlueColor(i1,_j),   getBlueColor(i1,j), getBlueColor(i1,j1),  getBlueColor(i1,j2),
                                        getBlueColor(i2,_j),   getBlueColor(i2,j), getBlueColor(i2,j1),  getBlueColor(i2,j2)};
                    double bA_B[4] = {(A[0]*blueB[0]+A[1]*blueB[4]+A[2]*blueB[8]+A[3]*blueB[12]),
                                      (A[0]*blueB[1]+A[1]*blueB[5]+A[2]*blueB[9]+A[3]*blueB[13]),
                                      (A[0]*blueB[2]+A[1]*blueB[6]+A[2]*blueB[10]+A[3]*blueB[14]),
                                      (A[0]*blueB[3]+A[1]*blueB[7]+A[2]*blueB[11]+A[3]*blueB[15])};
                    blue3 = (int)(bA_B[0]*C[0]+bA_B[1]*C[1]+bA_B[2]*C[2]+bA_B[3]*C[3])>>16;

                    //**************************************************************************************************************//
                    //**************************************************************************************************************//
                    //Ϊ�˵õ������Ⱥ���������������������һ���жϣ�������ڻ�С��ĳ��ֵ����˫�����㷨������ֵ�����������ξ���㷨�õ���ֵ
                    if(alpha3<0||red3<0||green3<0||blue3<0||alpha3>255||red3>255||green3>255||blue3>255){
                        colorpix = (alpha << 24)|(red << 16)|(green << 8)|blue;
                    }else{
                        colorpix = (alpha3 << 24)|(red3 << 16)|(green3 << 8)|blue3;
                    }
                //LOGI("c---> ca = %d",);
                (*env)->SetIntArrayRegion(env,image,(int) (y*_width + x),1,&colorpix);
                }
            }

}

JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL Java_com_test_mypicture_ui_WarpView_warpPhotoFromC
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jintArray imagearr, jint height, jint width, jdouble r,
                        jdouble orig_x, jdouble orig_y, jdouble cur_x, jdouble cur_y){
//��ʼ���ɫ����

    int len = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env,imagearr);

    int* color = (*env)->GetIntArrayElements(env,imagearr,0);

    int colors[len];

    int colorsOr[len];

    _width = width;
    _height = height;

    int i = 0;
    for(;i<len;i++){
        int colorpix = *(color+i);//��ǰ����ֵ
        colors[i] = colorpix;
    }
    colorsP = &colors[0];
    //Ť��ͼƬ��ӳ��

    int or_x = (orig_x-r)>0?(orig_x-r):0;//(int) Math.max((orig_x-r), 0);
    int or_y = (orig_y-r)>0?(orig_y-r):0;//(int) Math.max((orig_y-r), 0);

    int max_x = (orig_x+r)<width?(orig_x+r):width;//(int) Math.min((orig_x+r), width);
    int max_y = (orig_y+r)<height?(orig_y+r):height;//(int) Math.min((orig_y+r), height);
    int m = or_y;
    for(;m<max_y;m++){
        int n = or_x;
                for(;n<max_x;n++){
                    mapping(env,imagearr,n, m,r,orig_x,orig_y,cur_x,cur_y);
            }
     }
    return imagecolors;
}
//��ʼ�����ұ�
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_test_mypicture_MainActivity_initArray
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj){
        long k;
        for (k = 0;k<=(2<<8);++k){
            SinXDivX_Table_8[k]=(long)(0.5+256*MySin(k*(1.0/(256))))*1;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

> This is Java Code from where i invoke the C method.

package com.test.mypicture.ui;

```
import com.test.mypicture.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class WarpView extends View {
    static{
        System.loadLibrary("Warp");
    }
    public native int[] warpPhotoFromC(int[] image,int height,int width,double max_dist,
                                      double orig_x,double orig_y,double cur_x,double cur_y);

    private Bitmap mBmp;    // original bitmap
    private Bitmap newBmp;  // ARGB_8888 bitmap
    private int[] image;    // array of pixels
    private int[] colorR;
    private int[] colorG;
    private int[] colorB;
    private boolean fg = true;

    private static final int DEFAULT_PAINT_FLAGS =
            Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG;
    Paint mPaint = new Paint(DEFAULT_PAINT_FLAGS);


    public static int HWPPQ = 110; 
    public static int MMQFJ = 120;  

    private int MODE = MMQFJ;
    private double orig_x, orig_y;
    private double mou_dx,mou_dy;
    private double max_dist;
    private int width;  // image width
    private int height; // image height

    private float scale;
    private RectF dest;
    private double move_x,move_y;
    private int dist = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.max_dist);


    public WarpView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public WarpView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        //setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        dest = new RectF(0,0,0,0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //super.onDraw(canvas);
        if(fg){
            int viewWidth = getWidth();
            int viewHeight = getHeight();
            float scale1 = (float)width/(float)viewWidth;
            float scale2 = (float)height/(float)viewHeight;
            scale = scale1>scale2?scale1:scale2;
            float wscale = width / scale;
            float hscale = height / scale;
            int xoffset = (viewWidth-(int)wscale)/2;
            int yoffset = (viewHeight-(int)hscale)/2;
            dest.set(xoffset, yoffset, (int)wscale+xoffset, (int)hscale+yoffset);// = new RectF(xoffset, yoffset, (int) (width/scale)+xoffset, (int) (height/scale)+yoffset);

            canvas.drawBitmap(mBmp, null, dest, mPaint);

        }else{
            canvas.drawBitmap(newBmp,null, dest, mPaint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            orig_x = event.getX();
            orig_y = event.getY();
            orig_x = (orig_x-dest.left)*scale;
            orig_y = (orig_y-dest.top)*scale;

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                max_dist = dist*scale;//Math.hypot(mou_dx, mou_dy);
                if(event.getAction() != 1){


                    //int m = event.getHistorySize();

                    move_x = event.getX();
                    move_y = event.getY();

                    move_x = (move_x-dest.left)*scale;
                    move_y = (move_y-dest.top)*scale;

//                  if(m > 0){
//                      int i2 = m + -1;
//                      orig_x = (event.getHistoricalX(i2) - dest.left)*scale;
//                      orig_y = (event.getHistoricalY(i2) - dest.top)*scale;
//                  }
                    if(move_x >=0 && move_y >= 0){
                        warpPhotoFromC(image,height,width,max_dist,orig_x,orig_y,move_x,move_y);

                        newBmp.setPixels(image, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
                        fg = false;
                    }
                }
                orig_x = move_x;
                orig_y = move_y;

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
    public void setWarpBitmap(Bitmap bmp){
        fg = true;
        mBmp = bmp;
        width = bmp.getWidth();
        height = bmp.getHeight();
        newBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888/*Bitmap.Config.RGB_565*/);
        image = new int[width*height];

        mBmp.getPixels(image, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
        newBmp.setPixels(image, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
        //super.setImageBitmap(mBmp);
    }
    public void setMode(int mode){
        this.MODE = mode;
    }

    public Bitmap getWrapBitmap(){
        return newBmp;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you know where the crash occurs?

Comment: Somewhere in this method mapping(env,imagearr,n, m,r,orig_x,orig_y,cur_x,cur_y);

Comment: @sanidhya09 Could you provide crash trace from device's logcat?

Comment: @Serhio just this single line i get in crash Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 at tid(9854213). If you want i can provide a sample app on github by tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I just updated my build.gradle settings ndk configuration and it started to work in every device.

```
ndk {
            moduleName "native"
            toolchain "clang"
            toolchainVersion "3.5"
            CFlags.add("-DCUSTOM_DEFINE")
            cppFlags.add("-DCUSTOM_DEFINE")
            ldFlags.add("-L/custom/lib/path")
            ldLibs.add("log")
            stl "stlport_static"
        }
```